# How to filter by count on gremlin map (OrientDB)

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I have a somewhat similar business problem to - [Gremlin filter by count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973693/gremlin-filter-by-count)
, but I'm running on OrientDB 3.0.16

This query:

```
  g.V().hasLabel('skill').
   groupCount()
```

Returns from OrientDB, as expected:

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "com": 1,
        "netcompactframework": 1,
        "netremoting": 2,
        "netframework": 3,
        "net": 1,
        "netclr": 1
    }
],
"elapsedMs": 18
```

}

I tried to apply an unfold and where filter after it:

```
  g.V().hasLabel('skill').
   groupCount().
   unfold().
   where(select(values).is(gt(1)))
```

But I get an error:

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "reason": 501,
        "code": 501,
        "content": "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot convert netremoting=2 - class java.util.HashMap$Node to JSON"
    }
]
```

}

It seems that problem is with unfold() as OrientDB is trying to convert the map entry string into JSON and fails

Any ideas? 
Is this an OrientDB specific issue? Maybe there is another way to perform the same logic in gremlin?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a serialization error of some sort, but I'm not sure of the circumstance under which you are operating to get that problem. When you `unfold()` a `Map`, it gets converted to Java `Map.Entry` and returning that seems to be a problem for the serializer which along the way encounters the internal class `HashMap$Node`. I think you can work around this problem by folding back to a `Map`:

```
g.V().hasLabel('skill').
   groupCount().
   unfold().
   where(select(values).is(gt(1))).
   group().
     by(keys).
     by(select(values))
```

I would be curious to know what circumstances cause you to get that error. Standard GraphSON serializers in Gremlin Server should be able to handle `HashMap$Node` so it's curious that you'd be getting this problem at all.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for trying to help. I just tried running the query up to and including the unfold() (three first rows) and the same serialization error shows up. I'm starting to think this may be an issue with OrientDB implementation. Our skill vertices seem to be defined properly and otherwise work without any issues, with many other queries.

Comment: i'm confused. are you saying that you ran my entire query (not just the first three steps) and still got the same serialization error?

Comment: I run the query g.V().hasLabel('person').groupCount().by('name') on another little OrientDB database which is essentially the Toy data model (Marko, Vadas, etc.). It works fine.



But once I add .unfold() to the query the same serialization error occurs. 
"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot convert peter=1 - class java.util.HashMap$Node to JSON"
Therefore I don't think it is unique to the database I originally tried on (with skills)
    "result": [
        {
            "peter": 1,
            "vadas": 1,
            "josh": 1,
            "marko": 1
        }
    ]

Comment: Your query seems to missing a dot after the where row
But even after fixing that little syntax issue your query returns no results and also no error (which is odd)
As I wrote, I switched over to the tiny data model and the issue is reproducing.

Comment: it is not odd that you no longer get an error. i don't think you're seeing the point of my workaround. `unfold()` returns `HashMap$Node` which is not serializable for a reason i'm not clear on given what you've explained about your environment. by adding the additional steps after the `where()` we transform the `HashMap$Node` to a `HashMap` and that should serialize with no problems. The fact that you get no results should not have anything to do with that. I suggest that you remove the `where()` from my query suggestion and see if you get actual results.

Comment: You should also consider updating your question with more information about how you have your environment set up? Are you using Gremlin Server? are you submitting Gremlin scripts or using bytecode based requests? what language are you using to connect (java, javascript, python, etc)?